# Windows 10 (Build 1607) won't allow remote desktop connection

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

My laptop is running Windows 10, build 1607, and no longer allows remote desktop connections to be made. When it was running Windows 8 and the previous versions of Windows 10 (before the major updates) remote desktop connections worked perfectly fine. The machine can still *make* remote connections to other computers, but other computers (both Windows 7 and 10) can no longer 'see' it.

I have done all the obvious fixes and checks, ensuring my computer is on a local network, ensuring firewalls from both machines are disabled, checking to see if remote assistance is permitted on the machine (it is, at the option is enabled) and trying to access the computer via IP and computer name.

The problem is baffling- and the menu the lists the options for remote access seems to have changed from previous versions (screenshot attached)

[image: screenshot of my menu]

Comment: Windows HOME (Which is what your screen shot shows) doesn't allow incoming RDP connections.

Answer (score 0):

There are workarounds to use remote desktop on Windows 10 Home.

I haven't tried this:

1. Download the RDPWrap from GitHub: [rdpwrap](https://github.com/binarymaster/rdpwrap/releases/tag/v1.6) (freeware)
2. Extract the RDPWrap-v1.6.zip and run the install.bat with Admin Privileges.
3. And now check the settings of the Remote Desktop.
4. At listener port problems please run the update.bat  (in admin mode)
5. Start the RDPConf.exe to see or change the Remote Desktop Server settings
6. Test the connection via RDPchek.exe
7. On a different Windows device, start Remote Desktop Connection and connect to the Windows-10 Home Remote Desktop Server

Details: [Enable Remote Desktop on Windows-10 Home, how to?](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=129)

Or:

- There are other 3rd party solutions though which can be used with the Home version, including VNC, TeamViewer, Splashtop, Chrome Remote Desktop, LogMeIn, join.me, Mikogo.
- The most obvious solution: [Upgrade Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Pro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12384/windows-10-upgrading-home-to-pro)